# Large file copy timeout

Tags: windows-7, windows, file-transfer

I have a few videos up to 4 GB in size on an SD card. I am able to watch them and I think this proves they are intact.

But whenever I try to copy file larger than perhaps 1.5 GB, the operations dies after about 2 minutes saying it cannot read the source even though it was making good progress. I've had the same issue copying over USB from my camera directly.

Is there some blind timeout on copying a single file here? How can I tweak or bypass it?

In other words, how can I copy a large file that may need a few minutes from an SD card or USB to the hard drive?

Comment: I suggest you check your sd-card for errors. There could be a problem with it even tough you can watch the movie.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, no, there aren't timeouts that stop a file transfer if it has been *doing just fine*. If the transfer was stopped due to an error, there was most likely an actual error.

If you can watch the movie, that just means your movie player is a bit more robust than your file copy application. Which makes sense, as one just wants to translate the file into pretty pictures and the other should make sure the copy is identical to the original.

So you either need to be more resilient while copying (like Tom suggested) because the media is faulty, or you have to reconstruct the file from the portions you can read (with tools like [this](http://alter.org.ua/soft/win/bb_recover/) or [this](http://www.roadkil.net/program.php?ProgramID=29) possibly).

Another related tool I should is [TeraCopy](http://codesector.com/teracopy), might come in handy for this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use robocopy for large or large amount of files. It is a really good copy program. The parameter /r is for number of retries and the parameter /w is for the wait-time between the retries in seconds.

```
robocopy s:\myvideo.mp4 c:\videos\myvideo.mp4 /r:5 /w:5
```

Robocopy should be preinstalled on your Windows 7

Comment: should be or is?

Comment: @barlop It usually is preinstalled. But I cannot tell for certain that this is true for his machine. Someone may have removed it. Why is this relevant?

Comment: If it's preinstalled, then even if somebody removed it after, it is still preinstalled with windows 7.  If you know for certain that it is preinstalled with windows 7, then you shouldn't cast doubt on it, as that misleads people into thinking it might not be, when you know that it is.

Comment: @barlop But that's the point. It might not be there and you would have to download it. Maybe I don't understand what you are trying to say to me. English is not my native language by the way.

Comment: Are you willing to say that Robocopy is installed on Windows 7, for any windows 7 edition, including Windows 7 Starter?  Or have you only tested for it on e.g. Windows 7 ultimate?

Comment: @barlop You are starting to annoy me. What do you want? State your desire and I might comply. Why are you beating around the bush?

Comment: You said you had a language barrier and clearly you don't have the patience or willingness to conquer your language barrier, and even attempt to answer a question, so that is  about all there is to say.

Comment: @barlop You still did not say what you want...You could simply test if it is there or not on your own machine. I cannot be totally sure if it is available on his machine. How could I? I cannot connect to his machine. This is why I said "should be". If you want a download link I can add it. If you want a Windows feature list I will check that for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45627/discussion-between-tom-and-barlop).